# How does one get positive recurrence for hastings-metropolis theorem?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose $X_n$ is an irreducible markov chain with transition probability matrix $P_{ij}$. My text books says that if there exists $\pi_i>0$ for all $i$ such that $\pi_iP_{ij} = \pi_jP_{ji}$ for all $i,j$, then $\pi_i$ are the stationary probabilities of $X_n$.

My question how can I prove that

- $X_n$ is recurrent, i.e. that starting from state $i$, the probability of returning to $i$ is one?
- Is it possible to see that the conditions above imply that the markov chain is ergodic?

Comment: The condition $\pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j P_{ji}$ for all pairs $(i,j)$ of states means that $X_n$ is time-reversible. Since the chain is irreducible, this gives
$$
\sum_i\pi_iP_{ij} = \sum_i\pi_jP_{ji} =\pi_j\sum_i P_{ji} = \pi_j
$$
for each $j$, hence $\pi P=\pi$. It follows that $\pi$ is the unique stationary distribution of $X_n.

Comment: How does this show it is (1) recurrent and (2) ergodic?

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241179/time-reversible-markov-chain-and-ergodic-markov-chain

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\tau^i_k := \inf \{n\geq \tau_{k-1}^i : X_n = i\}$, $\tau_0 := 0$.
Assume $(X_n)_n$ is transient, then $\Bbb P _j(\tau^i = \infty) > 0$.

Note that with the Markov Property we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (P^n)_{ji} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bbb P _j(X_n = i) = \Bbb E _j\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{\{X_n = i\}}\right]\\ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \Bbb P_j (\tau_k^i < \infty, \tau_{k+1}^i = \infty) =  \Bbb P_j(\tau_1^i <\infty)P_i(\tau_1^i =\infty)\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \Bbb P_i (\tau_1^i < \infty)^k< \infty$$
which implies 
$$(P^n)_{ji} \rightarrow 0$$
as $n \rightarrow\infty$. If $\pi$ is a non trivial invariant probability measure, there is an $i$ with $\pi_i > 0$, but
$\pi_i = (\pi P^n)_i \rightarrow 0$. Contradiction.

I have no answer to your question about ergodicity yet, but it seems to me like a coupling argument.

Comment: If $S$ is the state space, then you require uniform convergence to zero of $P^n$ on $S \times S$, if I am not mistaken. But it seems to me you only get pointwise convergence using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(\tau_1^i < \infty)^k < \infty$.

Comment: Pointwise convergence it is, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\pi P ^n)_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_S \pi (dx) P^n (x,i) = \int_S \pi (dx) \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P^n (x,i)  = 0$ with dominated convergence.